# Claws Mail stuck in full-screen mode

Tags: claws

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and claws mail 3.8.0.  Suddenly and I don't know why, Claws was in full-screen mode and I cannot close it normally.  The menu at the top does not show. Now I have to go to "compose" so I can get my icons up, then left click and then quit.  I can't find any menu item to get it out of full-screen mode. We have been using ubuntu since April so we have some experience with it, but we are far from experts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the menu item `View -> Fullscreen`, or hit the default full screen hotkey F11.